# Maximum call stack size exceeded в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть такой код jQuery:

```
jQuery("div[id^='vs_video_']").on("click", function(){   
    bvfsc = $(this).find( "button.vs-fullscreen-control.vs-control.vs-button" ); 
    bvfsc.click();
})
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Классика! При клике на любом элементе надо сделать некую операцию, частью которой является клик на элементе... а он у нас обрабатывается, и там надо сделать клик... у вас программа "зацикливается"

Comment: А как делать так, чтобы не "зацикливался"?

Comment: хорошо подумать на что вы кликаете внутри обработчика.